# Should flexbox containers be used to add text to a page?

Tags: html

I am currently making a page with flexboxes, and when it comes to adding text areas, I wonder if I should make a new container for each text area or is it not the way to do ?

Let's say I have the following code for my page:

```
 <div class="flex-container">
 </div>
```

Should I do this :

```
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="containertextarea1">
    <p> text area 1 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="containertextarea2">
    <p> text area 2 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="containertextarea3">
    <p> text area 3 </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Or something else?

Thank you

Comment: That works fine enough if you are trying to have horizontally aligned columns of text.

Comment: Ok thank you, and generally speaking is it the proper way to do ? Or sometimes it's better to simply put directly the text into the area without having to specially making a container for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need columns in your **flex-container** you can use flexbox. I mean something like this. from your code I think you can use

directly in flexbox. that will reduce DOM size.
[image]

Here is the [CSSTrix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) Link for a better understanding of FlexBox

Answer (score 0):

As we know flexbox is a one-dimensional layout model, then until and unless you don't want these text areas to be spread in two dimensions(like in both column and row) then I think putting all text areas in one container is fine.